# MATCH_PARENT beside WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-layout

On a Dialog I want a MATCH_PARENT EditText left of a ImageButton with WRAP_CONTENT.
This would look like the picture below.

[Layout picture http://goo.gl/dxuS5](http://goo.gl/dxuS5)

I dont know how to solve this problem!
It's must programming only in java! I have no chance to write this in XML.

I have just use with LinearLayout. But the MATCH_PARENT swaps the ImageButton with WRAP_CONTENT.
Also I use RelativeLayout but this doesn't looks like so I want.

Comment: If you want to avoid xml you should avoid android

Comment: If you want a real answer, you should tell us what you are trying to do from a layman's perspective. What exactly needs to appear on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Dostn run becuase i must use Java. Not XML! Also i cant get Gravity on ImageButton.. Says Eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are putting these into a horizontally oriented LinearLayout:

```
EditText temp = new EditText(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
temp.setLayoutParams(params);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(vp);        
imageView.setImageResource(id);        

someLinearLayout.addView(temp);    
someLinearLayout.addView(imageView);
```